# Excluding out-of-stock products from Wordpress search results not working when using custom statuses

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, search-form

I am using custom statuses for my woocommerce products using the following code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_status_creation' );
function my_custom_status_creation(){

    $status_keys   = array(
            'retired'=>'Retired',
            'sold-ooaks'=>'Sold OOAKs',
            'consignment'=>'Sent to Consignment',
            'pickbox'=>'Out on Pickbox'
        );

        foreach ($status_keys as $status_key=>$label){

            $status_label = _x( $label, 'post', 'woocommerce' );

            register_post_status( $status_key, array(
            'label'                     => $status_label,
            'public'                    => true,
            'exclude_from_search'       => true,
            'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
            'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
            'label_count'               => _n_noop( $status_label.' <span class="count">(%s)</span>', $status_label.' <span class="count">(%s)</span>'),
        ) );
        }
}
```

However, when this code snippet is being used, the native function of being able to exclude out-of-stock products from search results no longer works (this option can be found woocommerce -> settings -> products -> inventory and checking "Hide out of stock items from the catalog").

I've tested this with other plugins/code deactivated, but out-of-stock products continue to appear in my search results.

I also thought that

```
   'exclude_from_search'       => true,
```

would exclude those results from search, but it doesn't seem to work either.

I also tried:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'misha_hide_out_of_stock_in_search' );

function misha_hide_out_of_stock_in_search( $query ) {

    if( $query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'meta_key', '_stock_status' );
        $query->set( 'meta_value', 'instock' );
    } 
}
```

This does prevent out-of-stock products, but it also prevents other search results (ie posts, pages, events) from appearing on the search archive.

How can I make sure that out-of-stock products do not appear in the search results while still getting non-products results such as posts/events/pages/etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try condition your code to only apply to "product" queries:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'misha_hide_out_of_stock_in_search' );

function misha_hide_out_of_stock_in_search( $query ) {

    if( $query->get('post_type') === 'product' && $query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'meta_key', '_stock_status' );
        $query->set( 'meta_value', 'instock' );
    } 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work either. I still get the out-of-stock products displaying. Note: the last closing bracket in your code ended up outside the code snippet

Comment: Can you try dumping in the method to see if it's correctly reached? And is the query correctly updated? As for your question, it seems the code was working correctly but applied to all queries. Also dump every single condition of the "if" statement to see why it is not triggering.

Comment: Thanks:) I am new at coding; could you give me an example of how to dump the query method? What is the variable exactly that I would dump? I tried var_dump on $query->get('post_type') but it was just giving me the theme's content blocks. I also tried echoing something inside the if statement, but nothing happened, ie that if condition was never getting met.

Comment: you can use `wp_die($variable)`, or `print_r`. First, test that the misha_hide_out_of_stock_in_search() method is correctly triggered with a dump inside. Then, move the dump inside the `if` statement on your product archive page. If not triggered, it means one of the if condition is not met. So you need dump all conditions outside of the if to check their value, and wich one is not "right", and why.

Comment: Okay, so, it seems like a couple of issues. First, the if condition  `$query->get('post_type') === 'product'` is never being met since it's looking for an exact match, and the query is by default actually set to "any" (I tried first setting it for posts, events, and products, but it's still the same issue in that I'd have so then say `$query->get('post_type') === array('post','event','product'` for the condition to be met. Second, even if I could target  'product' post_type, I think I'd need to merge it into an array with the other results.

Comment: "and the query is by default actually set to "any"" on wich page are you trying this code? Is it the official loop or a custom query?

Comment: Just the regular search page

Comment: The woocommerce search page? And are you putting the code in the woocommerce product loop?

Comment: It's my sitename.com/?s= which includes posts, pages, events, and products

Comment: Here is the sql request I saw using debug:
`SELECT   wp_posts.ID
     FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )
     WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_elementor_edit_mode' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'builder' )
) AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment', 'e-landing-page', 'product', 'ct_size_guide', 'event') AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'draft'))
     GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
     ORDER BY wp_posts.post_modified DESC
     LIMIT 0, 1`

Comment: Ah ok, I better understand now. Well, I don't think it's possible with a single wp_query. I would recommand doing a custom SQL query (see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/187744/query-multiple-post-types-each-with-own-meta-query)